# How to round a float in F#?

Tags: f#

Is there a function that can round a float in Fsharp?
Something like

```
round(3.21156,3) = 3,212
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
System.Math.Round (3.21156,3);;
val it : float = 3.212
```

Answer (score 18):

For reference, there are also built-in F# functions for `floor`, `ceiling`, `truncate`, and `round`; however, the built-in round function doesn't allow you to specify the precision like `System.Math.Round(...)` does.

Reference: https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html

Comment: I wonder why F#'s library doesn't give you the option to round to the nearest desired decimal.

Comment: I suspect because Math.Round does that through overloading and F# operators don't support it. The library could provide a different function though.

Answer (score 3):

good old multiply-divide by ten-to-the-power-of-the-precision-needed

```
round (3.21156 * 1000.) / 1000.
//3.212
```